# block files by extension using sftp

Tags: ssh, ftp, centos7, sftp, vsftpd

I had configured an ftp server in Centos 7, in which I used the vsftp package and in the vsftpd.conf file I used a command called deny_file in which I only indicated the file extensions that I would not allow to be uploaded to the server, however I saw that the ftp server was not safe and I wanted to put it secure with SSH, that is with SFTP, but despite having the deny_file in the vsftpd.conf it does not block the files by extension and I really want to know if any of you knows a way to do it

please help me,the other question is not explained clearly and I do not understand it.

Comment: Why do you say my question is duplicated, if I'm asking for another distribution and I'm using vsftpd ... besides the other answer is not clear, I'm not really that good with networking, but I try to learn and for more I have researched I do not understand how to do that, so I asked and I need help

Comment: AFAIK vsftpd doesn't implement SFTP. That's why vsftpd.conf doesn't have any effect on SFTP provided by OpenSSH. SFTP and FTPS are different protocols.

Comment: sorry, seriously believe me I do not know much about this and I want to learn, could you explain me well how to do it please

Comment: You've asked for something that is not possible without significant hacking. The linked question explains what is necessary. It is entirely possible that you will be unable to do it because you don't yet have the necessary knowledge or experience. In that case seek help from your senior admin or management.

Comment: I just want to filter according to the extension of the file, that is, if I upload an mp4, I do not allow it to upload it, in order I want the SFTP to control the files of a web page, that is, I do not want to upload files .rar . work of the university and I thought that in this page they helped